# STS unable to bind maven file (.m2)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm working on a maven project in Spring tool suite(STS), issue is unable to navigate to other classes and methods (using ctrl+ mouse click), and its showing many error messages near import statements and other places in the class.

When clicked on the red cross mark which states error and select **FIX project setup** below is the message displayed on popup window.

**The following proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'Bootstrap'
Add archive 'lpa-core-1.2.5.jar - c:\Users\tom.m2\repository\com\lpa\lpa-core\1.2.5' to buildpath of 'lpa-realtime-service'**

Please suggest how to include .m2 file automatically while build process to avoid the error messages and to navigate to other classes and methods using ctrl and mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your project is not properly set up so that the IDE doesn't really configure its classpath correctly. Normally this would all happen automatically via m2e (i.e. Eclipse's maven support).

M2e is included in STS by default, so its probably installed, but somehow your project isn't treated as a maven project.

You can try to re-import it using the proper 'import wizard' which should set things up correctly for you.

Steps:

1. Delete the project from the workspace. Take care not to actually delete the files themselves. (There's a checkbox 'Delete project contents on disk', so don't select that).
2. clean out all the 'junk' data from your project. Delete all tese files / folders from your project `.classpath`, `.project`, `.settings`, `target`.

Now that you have a 'clean slate'. Import it using m2e. Menu: File >> Import >> Existing Maven Projects".

This *should* setup everything correctly.

I say *should* because it depends to a large degree on what is in the project itself. But this, in principle, is the correct way to import maven project into STS (or Eclipse in general).